# Counting arrangements of seven people standing in a row of $3$ and a row of $4$, with $A$ and $B$ together, and with $A$ and $C$ separated

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> Seven people are standing in two rows, with three people in the front row and four in the back row. Among them, A and B must stand next to each other, while A and C must stand separately. How many different arrangements are there?

My thought process is like this, but the result is incorrect.

First, we consider the condition that A  and B  must stand next to each other. We can treat A and B as a single unit since they have to stand together.

Now we have 6 "entities" to arrange (5 people plus the A-B unit), with 3 spots in the front row and 4 in the back row.

Step 1: Choose 3 entities from the 6 to stand in the front row. There are $6 \choose 3$ ways to do this.

Step 2: The 3 entities in the front row can be arranged in $3!$ ways.

Step 3: The remaining 3 entities (including the A-B unit) in the back row can also be arranged in $3!$ ways. However, since A and B form a unit, there are actually only 2 arrangements (A on the left or A on the right).

Step 4: We need to subtract the arrangements where A and C  are standing together. If A and C are in the front row, there are $4 \choose 1$ choices for the third entity in the front row, and ${3 \choose 2} \times 2$ ways to arrange the back row (choosing 2 from the remaining 3 people with 2 arrangements each). If A and C are in the back row, there are ${4 \choose 2} \times 2$ choices for the other two people in the back row (choosing 2 from the remaining 4 people with 2 arrangements each), and $3 \choose 1$ ways to choose one person for the front row.

Therefore, the total number of arrangements is:
$$N = {6 \choose 3} \times 3! \times 3! \times 2 - {4 \choose 1} \times {3 \choose 2} \times 2 - {4 \choose 2} \times {3 \choose 1}$$

Calculating this we get:
$$N = 20 \times 6 \times 6 \times 2 - 4 \times 3 \times 2 - 6 \times 3$$
$$N = 1440 - 24 - 18$$
$$N = 1408 - 18$$
$$N = 1390$$

There are a total of 1390 different arrangements.

Comment: If AB is in the front row then there are only two entities in the front row, AB and one other person. You cannot choose three out of six entities for the front row since that can have either 3 or 4 people depending on whether you chose AB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One error that pops out in your solution is as follows. You consider $AB$ as one unit and then you consider the possibility to placing $3$ units in the first row. That means you are allowing the possibility of four people being in the first row ($AB$ as one unit and two others.)

Here's how I would solve this.

We start by ignoring the condition associated with $C$.

If $AB$ are in the first row, there can only be one another person in that row. So the number of ways for the first row would be ${5 \choose 1} \times 2 \times 2$. Multiplying this by $4!$ (for the second) we get the total number of ways in which $AB$ are in the first row ($=480$).

If $AB$ are in the second row, there can only be two other people in that row. So the number of ways for the second row would be ${5 \choose 2} \times 3! \times 2$. Multiplying this by $3!$ we get the total number of ways in which $AB$ are in the first row ($=720$).

So the total number of ways without the restriction for C would be $480 + 720 = 1200$

Next, let's find the number of ways in which $A$ and $B$, are together, as are $A$ and $C$. We consider the three as one unit that can be rearranged in $2$ ways ($CAB$ and $BAC$).

Now, if this group is in the first row, nobody else can be in that row. So total number of ways would be $2 \times 4! = 48$. If the three are in the second row, one other can be there. So, the total number of ways would be ${4 \choose 1} \times 2 \times 2 \times 3! = 96$. These add to $144$.

So, the required number is $1200 - 144 = 1056$.

Comment: +1 Also. : For what it's worth, minor shortcut to first part is to first assume that you have one row of $~7~$ people, which computes to $~2 \times 6!.~$  Then, the signficance of splitting the rows is that the AB unit must not be assigned seat--3, which by symmetrical considerations, has a $~\dfrac{1}{6}~$ probability of occurring.  So, you are left with $$\left[ ~1 - \frac{1}{6} ~\right] \times 2 \times 6!.$$

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you! That's neat.

Comment: @user2661923: Nice use of probability !

Answer (score 4):

$\textbf{Another Approach}$

$AB$ together can be put in $5$ places, and  will leave $5$ valid spots for $C$ if they start either row, else $4$ valid spots.
Ditto (mirror image) if we start with $BA$

Thus valid ways of placing $A,B,C = 2(2\cdot5+3\cdot4) = 44$,
and permuting the remaining $4$ people in the spots left,

Total permutations $= 44*4! = 1056$

Comment: @Haris: Thanks, I have submitted another approach.

Comment: +1 Well deserved.